AWS DRS no rds-pg-labs-vpc option
I followed the tutorial to create DB instance. In the step "In the Connectivity section, select the rds-pg-labs-vpc as the Virtual Private Cloud (VPC) value." I am unable to find the rds-pg-labs-vpc option in the virtual private cloud (VPC) field in the Connectivity section.
Changing area doesn't help. I'm current using us-east-2. Can anyone figure out what's the problem? Should I create a VPC?


Creating that VPC would be one of the prerequisites for doing the exercise. For some reason the prerequisites page is broken in that guide: https://catalog.us-east-1.prod.workshops.aws/workshops/2a5fc82d-2b5f-4105-83c2-91a1b4d7abfe/en-US/1-prerequisites/task2
